# Allow only single attachments to notes for a specific entity in ms crm 2013

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to allow only single attachment to a specific entity's note section.
I need to develop a plugin for the same. A message should be displayed to user informing him that only single document is allowed as per audit rules and user should contact Production Services to remove unwanted documents.

Please help me to understand on which entity and its event I need to fire my plugin.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Register a pre-operation synchronous plugin on the [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx#Anchor_1) message of [Annotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334398.aspx). In the plugin you would then see if there exists any other Annotations related to the same record (using the ObjectId field) that are attachments (using the boolean [IsDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593034.aspx#Anchor_0)).

In case another another Note with an attachment exists, you would then throw an exception with a message to the user, which would result in the Note not being created.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Just to confirm that my target entity will be Annotation. So how will I fetch the details of the parent record (for ObjectId)?

Comment: Which details do you need to fetch from the related record? Wouldn't it be enough to use the ObjectId to find all other Annotations with the same ObjectId?

Comment: Can u help me with a sample code to achieve this. I am new to plugin development.